# A generalized arithmetic progression is the union of a finite set and an arithmetic progression.

Tags: number-theory, logic

An ordinary arithmetic progression is a sequence $s: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $s(\lambda) = c \lambda + d$ where $c,d \in \mathbb{N}$.

A generalized arithmetic progression is a mapping $s: \mathbb{N}^k \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $s(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k)=a + \sum_{i = 1}^k \lambda_i b_i$ where $a,b_i \in \mathbb{N}$.

I want to prove that the image of a generalized arithmetic progression is the union of a finite set and the image of an ordinary arithmetic progression.

Comment: Subtract $a$, extract GCD of the $b_i$ and use [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_semigroup#Theorem) or imitate its proof. Kids call the case $k=2$ [the Chicken McNugget theorem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Chicken_McNugget_Theorem).

Comment: @owl I'm not sure I follow. I can write $s(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k)  - a = \sum_{i = 1}^k \lambda_i b_i = gcd(b_i) \sum_{i = 1}^k \lambda_i d_i$. But I'm not sure how the theorem helps.

Comment: The sums $\sum_i\lambda_ib_i$ are the subsemigroup generated by the $b_i$. If we have extracted the GCD already, the theorem proves that this is finitely many values together with all natural numbers from some point on (that it is a numerical semigroup). Going back to the original image we will get all multiples of the GCD starting from some point on together with the finitely many numbers and all of them translated by $a$. So, finitely many numbers together with an arithmetic progression which difference is the GCD.

Comment: What do you mean by "the number of the theorem"?